# Formulate Cramer's rule for solving systems of linear equations, stating conditions under which the rule is applicable.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Formulate Cramer's rule for solving systems of linear equations, stating conditions under which the rule is applicable. Prove Cramer's rule for systems of two equations with two unknowns.

So I just wanted to double check my logic for this question, would something along these lines be correct:

Rule - Only applicable for square matrices that have a non zero determinant.

$$a_1x + b_1y = c_1$$
$$a_2x + b_2y = c_2$$

$$x = \frac{D_1}D,y = \frac {D_2}D$$

Where
\begin{align*} 
D& = \begin{vmatrix}a_1&b_1\\a_2&b_2\\ \end{vmatrix} &
D_1 &= \begin{vmatrix}c_1&b_1\\c_2&b_2\\ \end{vmatrix} &
D_2 &= \begin{vmatrix}a_1&c_1\\a_2&c_2\\ \end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: can you formulate your for a general system $Ax=b$ with $A$ a $n\times n$ matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct formulation for the $2\times 2$ case but you still need to *prove* that these formulas work. So, to finish you must show that
\begin{array}{crcrcrcrcr}
a_1\dfrac{D_1}{D} &+& b_1\dfrac{D_2}{D} &=& c_1 \\
a_2\dfrac{D_1}{D} &+& b_2\dfrac{D_2}{D} &=& c_2
\end{array}
The first of these two equations is proved by
\begin{align*}
a_1\dfrac{D_1}{D} + b_1\dfrac{D_2}{D}
&= a_1\frac{\begin{vmatrix}c_1&b_1\\ c_2&b_2\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a_1&b_1\\ a_2&b_2\end{vmatrix}}+b_1\frac{\begin{vmatrix}a_1&c_1\\ a_2&c_2\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a_1&b_1\\ a_2&b_2\end{vmatrix}} \\
&= a_1\frac{c_1b_2-b_1c_2}{a_1b_2-b_1a_2}+b_1\frac{a_1c_2-c_1a_2}{a_1b_2-b_1a_2} \\
&= \frac{a_1c_1b_2-a_1b_1c_2+b_1a_1c_2-b_1c_1a_2}{a_1b_2-b_1a_2} \\
&= \frac{a_1c_1b_2-b_1c_1a_2}{a_1b_2-b_1a_2} \\
&= c_1\frac{a_1b_2-b_1a_2}{a_1b_2-b_1a_2} \\
&= c_1
\end{align*}
Can you prove the second equation?

Cramer's rule in the $n\times n$ case may be stated as follows.

The system $A\vec x=\vec b$ is solved by 
$$
x_j=\frac{\det A_j}{\det A}
$$
where $A_j$ is the $n\times n$ matrix obtained by replacing the $j$th column of $A$ with $\vec b$.

Comment: yes, I see. So without writing it all out, the proof for the secodn equation is near identical to the first.

Comment: Yes. Do you see how to formulate the statement in the $n\times n$ case?

Comment: I think my posted answer is correct?

Comment: @Jack looks good. I'll add a bit to my answer so you can see how I would phrase it.

Comment: Thank you for the help appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

So here my answer for $nxn$ case:

$$a_{11}X_1 + a_{12}X_2 + · · · + a_{1n}X_n = b_1$$
$$.........$$
$$a_{n1}X_1 + a_{n2}X_2 + · · · + a_{nn}X_n = b_n$$

Thist can be represented in a form $AX = b$, where
$$A = ∥a_{ij}∥, X = (X_1, . . . X_n)^T$$
$$b = (b_1, . . . b_m)^T$$

For each $i = 1, 2, . . . , n$ denoted by $A_{x_{j}}$
the matrix obtained from $A$ by replacing
the column $j$, i.e., $(a_{1j} , a_{2j} , . . . , a_{nj} )^T$ by $b = (b1, . . . bm)^T$
.